# Connecting to ReplicaSet on MongoDB Ops Manager from another service in the Kubernetes cluster giving MongooseServerSelectionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, kubernetes

**TL;DR**

Trying to connect from service in default namespace to mongodb ops manager replica-set service in mongodb namespace. I tried with all below connection string formats. But, connection getting closed.

- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=mongo-replica-set"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=mongo-replica-set"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?tls=false&ssl=false"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?tls=false&ssl=false"
- "mongodb+srv://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/?tls=false&ssl=false"
- "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=rs0"

**Longer Version**

I created replicaset deployment in  "MongoDB Ops Manager" ( mongodb namespace ) . I am trying to connect to replicaset from another service in default namespace

**Replica Set** - mongo-replica-set

**Number of Nodes** - 3

I tried with different connect string format. But, always connection getting closed. I whitelisted multiple IPs I could get from the service.

1.

```
const MONGO_URI = "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user"
    
    const options = {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        keepAlive: true
    };
    
    mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, options);
    
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:830:32)
        at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
        at /app/src/index.ts:52:20
        at step (/app/src/index.ts:33:23)
        at Object.next (/app/src/index.ts:14:53)
        at /app/src/index.ts:8:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/app/src/index.ts:4:12)
        at start (/app/src/index.ts:5:15)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.ts:63:1)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
        at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:547:25)
        at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-19384996922428388.js:60:25)
        at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
        at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-19384996922428388.js:62:14)
        at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:61:7) {
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'Single',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(1) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

2. 

```
const MONGO_URI = "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=mongo-replica-set"
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
        ...
{
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(1) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

3. 

```
const MONGO_URI = "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user"
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
....        
{
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(3) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

4. 

```
const MONGO_URI = "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=mongo-replica-set"

    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
       ...
{
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(3) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

5. 

```
const MONGO_URI = "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?tls=false&ssl=false"
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
....
{
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'Single',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(1) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

6. 

```
const MONGO_URI =  "mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?tls=false&ssl=false"
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
...
 {
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(3) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-1.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription],
          'mongo-replica-set-2.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

7. 

```
const MONGO_URI =  "mongodb+srv://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/?tls=false&ssl=false"
    
    MongoParseError: Ports not accepted with 'mongodb+srv' URIs
        at parseSrvConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:50:21)
        at parseConnectionString (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:556:12)
        at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:277:3)
        at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:222:5
        at maybePromise (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:719:3)
        at MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:218:10)
        at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:716:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:709:19)
        at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
        at /app/src/index.ts:53:20
        at step (/app/src/index.ts:33:23)
        at Object.next (/app/src/index.ts:14:53)
        at /app/src/index.ts:8:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at __awaiter (/app/src/index.ts:4:12)
```

8. 

```
const MONGO_URI = mongodb://mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/user?replicaSet=rs0
    
    MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 10.20.1.5:27017 closed
...       
 {
      reason: TopologyDescription {
        type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
        setName: null,
        maxSetVersion: null,
        maxElectionId: null,
        servers: Map(1) {
          'mongo-replica-set-0.mongo-replica-set-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017' => [ServerDescription]
        },
        stale: false,
        compatible: true,
        compatibilityError: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
        localThresholdMS: 15,
        commonWireVersion: null
      }
    }
```

What am I missing here? Thanks for any help

Comment: That's an awful lot of exceptions to go through, mate.

Comment: I tried to run Mongo as a ReplicaSet in Kubernetes like 6 months ago - so it's been a while..I am no Kubernetes expert... I believe what I had to do was add a DNS record to internal Kubernetes DNS to get this to work. If you exec into one of the containers, and try to ping that hostname, does it resolve? (or you could try using the IP instead of hostname). Again, I it's been a while since I messed with Kube + Mongo, but I do remember having issues getting it stood up.

Comment: Can you connect with the mongo shell? [This may also be helpful](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

Comment: @MattOestreich: I am able to connect using Compass when I do port-forward of the primary replica-set to my local. In that, I used this connection string mongodb://localhost:27017/users

Comment: @ParthShah: I have removed the similar stack trace lines to reduce the size of the question. Mainly the change is on the connection string

Comment: @MattOestreich: I followd this. https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/connect-from-inside-k8s/. I am using the format <k8s-pod-name>.<k8s-internal-service-name>.<k8s-namespace>.<cluster-name>

Comment: Can you run `kubectl get svc` and share the Mongo relevant services?

Comment: You are trying to fix too many things at the same time. Get a standalone server working with a mongo shell connection, then get RS working, then get your application in there. Follow everything in https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#deployment--configuration onward.

Comment: @D.SM: I am not sure how it is many things. I am able to connect to a standalone mongodb service. That is not the case here. I am trying to connect to a replicaset in MongoDB Ops Manager in different namespace.

Comment: @AmitBaranes: mongodb namespace services given below mongo-replica-set-svc      ClusterIP      None           <none>          27017/TCP
comments-replica-set-svc   ClusterIP      None           <none>          27017/TCP        
operator-webhook           ClusterIP      10.86.14.114   <none>          443/TCP          
ops-manager-db-svc         ClusterIP      None           <none>          27017/TCP        
ops-manager-svc            ClusterIP      None           <none>          8080/TCP         
ops-manager-svc-ext        LoadBalancer   10.86.0.254    xx.xxx.xxx.xx   8080:32592/TCP

Comment: Your question does not say that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `useUnifiedTopology: false` and only port-forwarding the replicaset primary pod. Then in the connection string, only pass one host, and no replicaset name.

This is the only thing that worked for me. You don't even need to port-forward the service, only the replicaset primary pod.